# SpeechRecognitionEngine stopped working in Win8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, speech, sapi

I developed a project using VS2010 in Windows 7, later i added the speech control to it, and everything was working fine. I changed my OS to Win 8 and tried running the project and it worked fine. But due to some reason I need to format my system and after that when I tried to run the project, the speech functionality is not working any more.

I need to install SpeechSDK 5.1 initially to run the project with speech functionality and after that I got the new Speech to Text tab under Speech recognition in Control Panel, but now in Win 8 I am not able to see it (even after installing Speech SDK). Surprisingly the project was working fine in Win 8 only before formatting.

I have build, rebuild, clean the project but with no luck.

From default Speech Recognition provided in Windows, everything is working fine.

Please help !

Comment: Could you be more clear on "not working any more"?  Are you getting errors, is there something that isn't show up on the UI, etc?

Comment: Nothing happens, I tried to debug the code by setting the break-point in VS, but the control is not getting into the SpeechRecognised event code block !

Comment: I tried to create new project with Speech, but same problem, I doubt i am missing something extra. Might be any dll or reference ! But I checked everything is in place and what would I be missing, I think if I get the Speech to Text tab under Speech recognition in Control Panel, that will do the work, but don't know how to get that initially installing Speech SDK did that but now don't know what happened !

Comment: Even tried with System.Speech.dll version 3 and 4, nothing helped.

Comment: Got it working by changing the language of Windows Recognizer from UK to US under Speech Recognition !

Comment: That's interesting.  You should post it s an answer, so people can vote it up

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by changing the language of Windows Recognizer from UK to US under Speech Recognition !